# Yield something when random block of calculations passed

Tags: ruby, block, yield

The part I don't understand is how to make this yield so that the elements in the array have the calculation, (which is specified in the block), done to them `if block_given?`, prior to their being added together.

For example, the calculation could be `|x| x+3` (to add 3 to each of the elements), but I want this to work for any sort of manipulation of the elements, such as `|x| x**3` or `|x| x*5`, so that the elements in`my_ary` (`[1,2,3]`) are changed as specified by the calculation.

So essentially I'm asking what I need to do to the part of my code that reads `yield array.each{|x|} if block_given?` . what I was trying to do here is say that each element in the array should have whatever is stated in the block done to the element, so that it is changed.

What I am passing to the this is something along the lines of `my_ary.sum(2) {|x| x **4}`.

```
class MyArray
  attr_reader :ary

  def init(ary)
    @ary = ary
  end

  def sum(init_val = 0)
    yield ary.each{|x|} if block_given? 
    (@ary.inject(0){|x,y|x+y}) + init_val 
  end
end
```

Comment: Please improve your question. It is not clear what you are saying.

Comment: Hi sawa, is that more clear?

Comment: What is the first `end` referring to? It looks like you are trying to combine a braces notation with `if` and a `do...end` but there is no `do`. Are you trying to pass the block to the `sum` method? If so, shouldn't you be doing something more like `def sum(init_val = 0, &block)`?

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments, edit your question to have the full code sample.

Comment: Use `@sawa` (`@` at, as fair I remember it's called notifications). Without this, sawa won't be notified about your comment, but I may be wrong. Well, I am very confused about what you are asking.  **I think** that you want: `arr=[1,2,3]` and then apply method `sum`: `arr.sum(10){|x| x+4}`. 1. `[1+4, 2+4, 3+4]`(applying `x+4` to all elements of the array). Then you sum all elements: 1+4+2+4+3+4=18. And at the end add 10(18+10). Am I right? ps. your first edit was better.

Comment: Hi @DarekNędza, thanks for the tips. Yes, you are right - what I am trying to do is apply the method sum (in this way or a similar way): arr.sum(10){|x| x+4}, resulting in the array used for the calculation ebcoming [1+4, 2+4, 3+4], as you've said, and finally adding the 10 (from sum(10) at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyArray
  attr_reader :ary

  def initialize(ary)
    @ary = ary
  end
  def sum n, &block
    new_ary = @ary.collect &block # ary after executing block
    ary_sum = new_ary.inject(0){|sum, x| sum+=x} # sum all elements of the array
    return ary_sum + n 
  end
end
```

`def nsum n, &block`, here `&` *saves* the block (code between `{}` or `do; end`) to instance of `Proc`. It's basically your block of code saved to variable.

`@ary.collect &block` here, `collect` want `block` not `proc` so `&` change `proc` to the `block`. `collect` execute block for each element, and return new array.

`inject` - yields element to the block, add it to `sum`, and it is returned as `sum` variable. On the next iteration (next yielding to the block) `sum` will be last value of previous iteration.

```
[1,2,3].inject(0){|s, x| s+=x} 
# sum = 0; x = 1;
# sum = 1; x = 2
# sum = 3; x = 3
# sum = 6 
# inject returns 6 because there is no elements in the array
```